# Adding border around continents in custom map theme

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api

I would like to create a retro nuclear-war movie style strategic map, such as the one below:

[image]

All I can get is this, missing the border around the oceans/continents, which is much less useful:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using a line Land boundary dataset for countries instead of a polygon dataset for countries.
Here is a polygon dataset for countries = https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/world-administrative-boundaries/export/